# How do I select all records having the max value in a column in SQL?

Tags: sql

Suppose I have the following Database:

```
Create table Employee (emp_id int, emp_name varchar(20), staff int);

Insert into Employee values(101,"John", 3);    
Insert into Employee values(102,"Mary", 3);    
Insert into Employee values(103,"Smith",2);    
Insert into Employee values(104,"Bill", 2);    
Insert into Employee values(105,"Kelly", 1);
```

I want it to select print John and Mary, because they have the highest staff, i.e. 3. Could anyone please shed some light?

I have tried doing:

```
select emp_name from Employee having staff = max(staff);
```

but i keep getting an error!

Comment: Are you Really using MySQL and SQLite and SQL Server and PostgreSQL?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a subquery that returns the max staff of the table:

```
select e.* from Employee e
where e.staff = (select max(staff) from Employee)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
= (SELECT MAX(staff) FROM Employee)
```